# Logic Pro X - Mapped instruments and staff styles not pasting properly

Tags: daw, logic-pro

I do a lot of work with sampled instruments and take advantage of the facilities of mapped instruments and staff styles. Once I've created them I want to be able use them in other projects. The problem is, they don't paste properly between projects.

When I copy a mapped instrument from one project and paste it to another, all my custom groups are gone and replaced by * New Group. When I copy and paste a staff style, all the group assignments are there, with the correct positions, but the pop up Drum Group menu is empty. Those custom groups are nowhere to be seen in either the staff styles or mapped instruments interfaces.

**Addendum**

What would be good, would be to know where Logic Pro X stores the default group names and to be able to add them there globally - or some similar facility. I've scoured the Logi Pro X preferences and have not been able to find anything with the default names in.

Comment: I haven’t worked with logic pro yet. But in other programs there is a filter in the copy menu where you can choose which elements shall be copied and which not. So you can prevent that some features won’t be edited or over written. Maybe you’ll find something similar in your program. Look for “filter”.

Comment: There is no filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but instead a sort of workaround. I'm doing this until a proper solution appears.

Having experimented further I've discovered that if I open up the mapped instrument and write the names back in that I only have to do each unique group name once, because, where it was originally used multiple times the rest update immediately, so that even though you only see a forest of * New Group, it does remember which is which underneath. The bonus is that the appropriate selected group names then reappear in the staff style and the group name menus become active again.

The down side, is that after this, there is a bunch of group names left in the menu all called * New Group, which is a not pretty.